# Any benefit for targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1 instead of 4.5?

Tags: .net

The .NET Framework 4.5.1 does not have a lot of [API additions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/08/07/documentation-updates-for-net-4-5-1.aspx). Besides access to those API additions, is there any reason to **target** 4.5.1 rather than 4.5 for building? All the 4.5.1 .NET Runtime performance benefits will be obtained simply by using the new Runtime, correct?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/06/26/announcing-the-net-framework-4-5-1-preview.aspx

Comment: There's no "besides", the only reason to target 4.5.1 is to gain access to those few api additions.  If you do then you force your user to update as well.

Comment: Cool, thanks Hans. I just wanted to confirm. I'd mark that as the answer if it was one instead of a comment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two reasons I can think of:

1. As Hans mentioned, if you're using one of the new API additions it's necessary. First Floor Software has a [diff](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/Media/DiffLists/.NET%204.5-vs-.NET%204.5.1.html) you can look at.
2. You'll be notified if you're using an API that Microsoft has deprecated in .NET 4.5.1.